# Mimic Activity transition animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I transition between activities, I use the following for the transition animation:

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_rtl, R.anim.slide_out_rtl)`

Where slide_in_rtl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="330"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
```

and slide_out_rtl looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="330"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"/>
```

The code above works, but I would like to mimic this behavior while NOT transitioning between activities. That means, I want to stay in the same activity, but let the user feel like a new activity is presented.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Natezz, research ViewPager, thats what you are looking for

Comment: Or you cad do it by Fragments